# jQuery hover element fadeout / fadein child element without looping

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I've been trying many routes without a solution: I'm trying to hover on an element, fadeout a child element, pause for a duration of time, and then re-fadein the same child element again. I'm trying .queue, and .stop even together here—not working. Tried tons of variations of this too.

```
$('.project').mouseover(function(){
    $('.skill h2', this).fadeOut(500).queue(function(){
        $(this).stop(true,true).fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

Comment: Try using delay(). Used to delay animations in queue
Also add a jsfiddle plz. Also fadeOut and fadeIn have a callback function. Dont queue it but use a callback.

Comment: Tried delay in many ways, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/khT5L/4/

Comment: I guess thats working

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **[.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)**:

> Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue

```
$('.project').mouseover(function(){
    $('.skill h2', this).fadeOut(500).delay(1000).fadeIn(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is to keep the parent element as it is.
FadeOut will cause display:none to the div and hence your parent element will collapse unless you give it a fixed height and width.

Also you have added "this" in your jquery call which will also cause the parent or the invoking element to go into fadeout.

add this to your css.

```
.project{
    height:80px;
    width:367px;
}
```

OR any dimension.

Make your jquery like this

```
 $('.project').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.skill h2').fadeOut(500,function(){
       setTimeout(function(){
         $('.skill h2').fadeIn(400);console.log('here');
        },1000);
    });
  });
```

check out this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/khT5L/6/